# Calculating inter-rater reliability with 1 primary rater and a couple other secondary raters

Tags: spss, reliability, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa, cronbachs-alpha

I'm trying to figure out what to use to calculate inter-rater reliability for a set of behavioral coding. There's one individual codes the whole set (primary coder; e.g. codes data ID 1-300) and a few other secondary coders who codes different sections of the data (Person A codes 1-100, Person B codes 101-200, Person C codes 202-300).

I'm not sure how to find the reliability in this case. I'm leaning towards separate Cohen's Kappa scores for each of the rater.

Comment: See chapter 11 "Inter-Rater Reliability: Conditional Analysis" in Gwet (2014) for a discussion of this type of analysis.

Gwet, K. L. (2014). Handbook of inter-rater reliability: The definitive guide to measuring the extent of agreement among raters (4th ed.). Advanced Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

If you compute $\kappa$ for each of the three subsets you can then summarise it either by taking the median or by a weighted mean with weights the inverse of the sampling variances. That gives you the average agreement of a secondary rater with the chosen primary rater. If the primary rater is seen as a gold standard, perhaps because they are highly trained and the others are beginners, then computing sensitivity and specificity for each subset would seem a better option.